# Getting all possible data from Solr 5.0

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm working in project using Solr 4.4 as data storage and I wanted to upgrade to Solr 5.0.

The problem is that when I was sending the query using solrj to get all possible results, the query was as following:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addSort("sorting_score", ORDER.desc);
query.addFilterQuery("label_list:\"" + currLabel + "\"");
query.set("rows", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

(I know that may be wrong because it can get too much data but this was my case)

this code works fine in Solr 4.4 but when I migrated to 5 it results `NegativeArraySizeException` exception and this was the error

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/Event: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:56)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:37)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.<init>(ShardDoc.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:955)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:743)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:722)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:350)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:144)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2006)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with `query.set("rows", Integer.MAX_VALUE);` Instead of trying to get as many rows as possible, use the paging mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in all those data you should use the deep paging iteration as described here: http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, there is a reference to Filter and we can see Filter Query param in your code snippet. Please try removing it and execute the query. You can always try the query first may be using curl and see before you come with java. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I know its late. This issue is because of query.set("rows", Integer.MAX_VALUE);.